# For /F "skip=0" won't work as expected

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

```
set var=1
for /f "skip=%var% tokens=*" %%a in (any.txt) do (echo %%a)
```

works fine.
But when,

```
set var=0
for /f "skip=%var% tokens=*" %%a in (any.txt) do (echo %%a)
```

won't work. My purpose is to skip line 0 (which means don't skip). 
Error: `tokens=*"` was unexpected at this time.
Is there any ways to make it work?

Comment: yes.`skip=0` just does not work.

Comment: So how to tell `for` command to don't skip line without removing `skip=%var%`?

Comment: with if condition...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set /P var="Enter number of lines to skip: "
if %var% gtr 0 (set "skip=skip=%var% ") else (set "skip=")
for /f "%skip%tokens=*" %%a in (any.txt) do (echo %%a)
```