# How to use increment value for SKIP in FOR loop of Batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to use an incremented value for SKIP in FOR loop of batch script, below is code snippet which I tried but this not working. Please help if someone have any idea about this. This is requirement related to comparison between 2 files and logically I have to compare whether each from file1.txt contains in file2.txt or not. It is possible that file1.txt have 3 lines and file2.txt may have 30 lines. I had used code like below snippet:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set /A result_count=1

echo !result_count!
echo %result_count%
set "result="

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%x in (file2.txt) do (

  for /F "skip=%result_count% delims=" %%r in (file1.txt) do (
    if not defined result set "result=%%r"
  )
  
  if "!result!" == "%%x" (
        echo Passed
  ) else (
        echo Failed
  )
  
  set /A result_count+=1

)
```

**Outputs:**

1. `!result_count!` have incremented value.
2. `%result_count%` did not have incremented value.
3. Not able to use `!result_count!` as `skip=!result_count!` in for loop.

**Expectation**

1. Either I can use `!result_count!` as `skip=!result_count!` in for loop.
2. Or `%result_count%` should have incremented value.

Comment: Is this the total code? Because it does not look like `result_count` is incremented anywhere before your loop... Oh and: DOS. IS. NOT. CMD. Just wanted to mention once again!

Comment: @geisterfurz007, this just the code snippet but logic is exactly same as I need. Updated the incremental line as well.

Comment: I see. But what are you trying to achieve? Like this you are looping through the file as leaving `skip` and your variable out if I am not mistaken...

Comment: Basically I want to read specific line from one file and search same line existence in another file. Found code << for /F "skip=4 delims=" %%i in (xprtest.txt) do if not defined xprvar set "xprvar=%%i" >> to do same. In same code snippet I tried with a variable for skip value which initial value is 1 and it should increment to read the next line before come to second time in for loop. I am strict to read one at line time and want to read specific line with a variable value as skip value.

Comment: So concept: Read through file up to appearance of one specific phrase, note line of it, use noted line to check in other file?

Comment: Updated little bit more in my code snippet which I am still trying, please refer same. Also updated the description.

Comment: Now I get it! That was a good edit you have done there :) You should be using `!result_count!` there. Look for questions like "Variable not updated in for loop batch" or something like that here on SO. You will get explanations from there a lot!

Comment: I tried lot of solution but did not get success to achieve my expectation. :( That's why posted this question.

Comment: Delayed expansion doesn't work for the options of the `for /f`. Check my answer

Comment: @AbhishekYadav did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: @J.Baoby Thanks it works for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use delayed expansion in the `for /f`-options. You can only use the normal variable expansion `%var%`.
The most easy solution in your case is to move the inner `for /f` in a function. Inside the function you won't have to worry about delayed expansion and will be able to use `%result_count%`.

Still there are some logical errors in your code:

- You don't unset your `result` variable at the end of each iteration in the outer loop. This will have the effect that the variable will only be set once (at the very first time) because after that `if not defined result` will never be taken (`result` contains its first value).
- The option `skip=n` will let the loop skip the first n lines. As you start with `result_count=1` you'll never process the first line in `file1.txt`. In the description you said you'd like to compare all lines. You should then start with `result_count=0`. Unfortunately [**"`skip` doesn't like 0"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205233/for-f-skip-0-wont-work-as-expected) (link is a question about the `skip=0` problem and a solution for it).

After the changes, I've moved the paths for `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` in variables (resp. `file1` and `file2`) to make it easily accessible and modifiable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set /A result_count=0

echo %result_count%
set result=
set file1=file1.txt
set file2=file2.txt

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("%file2%") do (
  call :innerLoop
  if "!result!" == "%%x" (
        echo Passed
  ) else (
        echo Failed
  )
  set result=
  set /A result_count+=1
)

exit /b 0

:innerLoop
IF %result_count% LEQ 0 (
    set skip=
) ELSE (
    set skip=skip=%result_count%
)
for /F "usebackq %skip%delims=" %%r in ("%file1%") do if not defined result set "result=%%~r"
exit /b 0
```

Comment: You are specifying the option `usebackq` of `for /F`, so you need to enclose the file within `""`, like `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("%file2%") do ( ... )`; I would also do the same for the other `for /F %%r` loop. Additionally, use the more secure `set` syntax `set "VAR=Value"`...

Answer (score 0):

Another options could be that of saving `for /f` loop options inside a variable:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set /A result_count=0

echo !result_count!
echo %result_count%
set "result="

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("file2.txt") do (

  :skipline
  if !result_count! gtr 0 (
    echo Count is greater than zero.
    set "opts=skip=!count! delims="
  ) else (
    echo Count is equal zero.
    set "opts=delims="
  )

  for /F "%opts%" %%r in (file1.txt) do (
    if not defined result set "result=%%r"
  )

  if "!result!" == "%%x" (
        echo Passed
  ) else (
        echo Failed
  )
  set result=
  set /A result_count+=1

)
```